# DIV's not recognized in FF + Opera, Works in IE + Chrome

Tags: firefox, html, css-float, opera, widget

I've tried and tried so hard to overcome this problem the past few days as I just want to get this site launched above all now. I have been developing this for the last week or so and I have been using my specific preferred browser, Google Chrome. Yes, big mistake!

Anyway, here is the demo site which shows what I want near everything to look like (apologies for some things that are out of place, haven't quite finished yet!): http://www.weburton.co.uk/content/demo/

You see the social area? It displays properly in Chrome; exactly as I want it. In IE it displays the div areas, but there are some styling issues such as the text on the Twitter side.

However, the div areas are completely ignored in other browsers it seems; its a strange problem, I'll admit that. I have them encased in a div which has a background image (selenasocial) and then have the other divs floating. Here is the code (CSS):

```
#selenasocial {
background: url(images/wls/social-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    display: inherit;
width: 100%;
min-height: 263px;
z-index: 555;
border: none; 
    overflow:auto;}

.selenasocial {
background: url(images/wls/social-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    display: inherit;
width: 100%;
min-height: 263px;
    z-index: 255;
border: none; 
    overflow:auto;}

.selenasocial img {
border: none;}

.twitsocial {
float: left;
width: 480px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
border: none;}

.facesocial {
float: left;
width: 480px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
border: none;}
```

And here is the HTML, I am using Widgets (and yes, they have been styled correctly in functions.php):

```
<!-- Selena Gomez Social Networks -->

<div class="selenasocial">


<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Social Sidebar") ) : ?> <?php   endif;?>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Social Sidebar 2") ) : ?> <?php   endif;?>
</div>
```

I overcame the error in IE (as it was happening there, too) by copying the CSS above into a separate IE.css file. I just don't understand why two browsers which are leaps and bounds ahead of IE aren't reading from the main CSS file.

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated - I've been tearing my hair out about this for the past few days.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's (technically) nothing wrong with your code - the part you posted. You are setting both float properties to left, which I guess is not what you want, but that did not explain why the other properties were getting ignored.

I won't read your 4700-lines CSS file to find what is wrong with it but I will try to help you do it yourself.

The first thing I did was to try to hunt the CSS code you posted with firebug and, to my surprise, it was not there. The very last line of CSS firefug gave me was the 902th which was this:

```
    .clearfix {
        zoom: 1;
    }
```

Actually, firebug did not show that zoom thing (the brackets were empty). So I went to the CSS file directly to find it out and, after wondering why would anyone use such non-standardized property, I checked the next lines to find there was a parentheses instead of a bracket in the 907th line.

After finding such error I proceeded to run a [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) on your CSS file and results were not very good. Fix those errors and Firefox will draw that properly.

Deciding whether IE and Chrome's capability of interpreting wrong CSS files is actually good or bad is not to be discussed here but learning how to find and correct your mistakes can help you get things to work with stricter browsers.

Comment: ... Well, I feel like a dumbass.

Thank you so much for your help there. You really saved me as I was about to start this whole damn theme again. 

You're a star. :-)